# Steps to take before trying to implement screen space ambient occlusion

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting, ssao

I very recently started learning modern OpenGL. I have implemented a wavefront file loader and a basic ADS shading model. At some point I'd like to implement screen space ambient occlusion. I tried reading on the technique and I understand the concept, but I have trouble understanding the details (i.e. extracting the depth information and reconstructing the positions in space etc.).

Thus the question is, what techniques should I learn/practice before trying to implement the SSAO?

Comment: Why not just ask about the problems you're having with implementing SSAO?

Comment: Because at the moment I'm having too many problems, I thought it'd be asking too much. So asking for a few pointers to get me in the right direction seemed more appropriate.

Comment: @user1294203: Well, asking about actual problems will get you actual answers. Asking for advice will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred rendering. 90% of what you need to implement SSAO is found in basic deferred rendering algorithms. That's one reason why SSAO is often used by deferred renderers; it's a natural fit.